# Retrieving geo location in my app is far less accurate than what Google Maps app shows in the same time on my device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

In my app, I've tried two ways of accessing location:

a) Using LocationManager and GPS_PROVIDER. I accept location to be processed if it has accuracy 50 or less. App receives location however most of the time receives no location at all - while Google Maps when I start it to try it out gets my location constantly and more precise than my app.

Here are parts of the source related to this:

Start to listen to locations:

```
// in service class, function to start listening for locations.
// class implements android.location.LocationListener interface
this.locman = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if( !this.locman.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ){
    Log.d("","GPS is not enabled");
}else{
    this.locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    this.onLocationChanged( this.locman.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) );
}
```

android.location.LocationListener implementation of onLocationChanged function:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ... showing provided Location on the map
}
```

in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This can give me relatively frequent updates, but sometimes has huge gaps. I believe maybe it's problem with connecting with enough satellites, however if I open Google Maps in the same time - it works flawlessly. No time gaps between location updates, and more precise than what I am getting here.

I thought it may be needed to use LocationClient and LocationRequest instead, counting that maybe Google Play API may have some internal interpolation / prediction / whatever that improves precision.

b) Using GooglePlay API with LocationClient and LocationRequest. I've installed Google Play SDK, and also tried Google's sample apps. Here is my code related to this:

```
// in service class, function to start listening for locations.
// class implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
// com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.OnConnectionFailedListener and
// com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks interface
this.locclient = new LocationClient(this.getApplicationContext(),this,this);
this.locclient.connect();
```

implementation of onConnected:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) 
{
    LocationRequest req = LocationRequest.create();
    req.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    req.setInterval(2000); // 2 sec
    req.setFastestInterval(16); // 60 fps
    this.locclient.requestLocationUpdates(req, this);
}
```

And of course onConnectionFailed and onDisconnected is implemented and breakpointed - never gets in, while onConnected is called.

Implementation of com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ... showing provided Location on the map
}
```

In this case, I get updates immediately, however off for like 200m or more.

In desperation, I tried MyLocation app that is on Google Play and it shows SAME OFFSET!

When I try Google Maps, in the same time, it shows absolute accuracy like 5-6m the most.

Important notice: I am located in Shanghai, China. Not sure if this is related in any way.

How is it possible to have such huge offset between Google Maps and Google's own example of location service (MyLocationDemoActivity.java, provided in google_play_services/samples/maps/)?? To clarify: Google's map demo provided with Google Play Services sample codes, also shows SAME OFFSET (~200m) away from my real location, while in the same time Google Maps app shows precise location.

I'm using Nexus 4 as development platform.

Compiler is ADT (Eclipse). All up-to-date.

Really hope for some quick breakthrough from anyone here!!! Thanks in advance!

P.S.

I have now tried to use LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER as setting for location request, to have my app get location update only when another app requested it. I've then started Google Maps, and switched back to my app. It immediately received location. I've copied long/lat into http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31.229179,121.422615&zoom=16&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap to test it out, and it is showing SAME OFFSET. While Google Maps on my phone shows exact location.

Is it possible that maps from Google have offset? Or that there is an offset to long/lat received?

Comment: The only workaround I could come up with was to add long/lat offset correction. For Shanghai, at very least, where I could test, offset was: double long_off = 0.004535; and double lat_off = -0.001779; I've tested this by walking around (alot), in open space (streets, squares) as well as indoor (coffee shops etc.). Once I would add this offset to long/lat received in the app, I could open map on http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap....... and see my correct position. But this is far from real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet so I'm writing an answer.

This is most likely related to the China GPS offset problem. The Chinese government insists on not allowing users to record accurate GPS data in some scenarios ("national security something blah blah") and force companies like Apple/Google to abide by the local laws.

Here is a link with some good information on the topic:
http://www.sinosplice.com/life/archives/2013/07/16/a-more-complete-ios-solution-to-the-china-gps-offset-problem

Comment: Thanks for comment. Interesting is how Apple Maps is working correctly though, as well as Google Maps. Anyway, I've created production tool that compares maps from Baidu, Google and few other sources for same GPS location and found a way to calculate offset for desired city in China. It's interesting that offset is not the same for all cities, but can vary a lot. So I have some sort of spread sheet with correction offsets loaded with the app, as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I would think that the gov provides Google/Apple with similar data sets as what you use in exchange for them keeping their apps in line with the gov's wishes. I read something that giving an accurate single location for yourself is ok, but recording "paths" of exactly where you have walked/driven is not allowed. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As in above answer, offset is because of China government regulation. However people managed to get transform used at least by GoogleMaps and HEREMaps. It is [here](https://on4wp7.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21455#EvilTransform.cs) written in C#.
Using that you can convert real coordinates to transformed ones with maximum 20 meters error. There are also more accurate implementations.

If you don't want to modify your software, you can use something based on [this](https://github.com/skritland/GPSOffsetFix). It is my simple Xposed module to convert coordinates for all applications using LocationManager.